# SwiftUI View displayed with blue background

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, swift5

I'm trying to reproduce the Apple tutorial(Composing Complex Interfaces) and I have a very weird problem. My `CategoryItem` view is being displayed as a blue frame.

If I remove the `NavigationLink` which wraps it, everything works fine but with that one it doesn't.

```
struct CategoryRow: View {
    var categoryName: String
    var items: [Landmark]

    var body: some View {

        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(self.categoryName)
                .font(.headline)
                .padding(.leading, 15)
                .padding(.top, 5)

            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(self.items) { landmark in
                        NavigationLink(
                            destination: LandmarkDetail(
                                landmark: landmark
                            )
                        ) {
                            CategoryItem(landmark: landmark)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.frame(height: 185)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: From the code you have posted it is going to be difficult to discern what is causing the blue view. Downloading and running the [tutorial's complete code](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/composing-complex-interfaces) works as expected. I would suggest comparing the code in the completed project with our own project ,using a diffing tool, so that you can see where the differences are and what might be causing your error.

Comment: Well I checked each line and its the same thing. Smth must have been updated I think

Comment: Even if you replace `CategoryItem(landmark: landmark)` with smth else like text or image it will be still blue

Comment: Do you get the blue view if you run the completed project? Also which version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: Does calling the `.renderingMode(.original)` on the Image inside the CategoryItem do anything? And for the text you could try explicitly calling `.foregroundColor(.black)`.

Comment: wow. it worked! thanks... but why....?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`NavigationLink` has a blue accent color by default, just call `.accentColor(Color.clear)` on it

Or you could try this:

```
NavigationView {
    NavigationLink(destination: Text("Detail view here")) {
        Image("YourImage")
    }
    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
}
```

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-disable-the-overlay-color-for-images-inside-button-and-navigationlink

Answer (score 5):

`renderingMode(.original)` is what did it for me; `.accentColor(Color.clear)` made the image invisible (my best explanation here is because it didn't have a transparency).

```
NavigationView {
    NavigationLink(destination: Text("Detail view here")) {
        Image("YourImage")
            .renderingMode(.original)
    }
}
```

As the answer above mentioned, [How to disable the overlay color for images inside Button and NavigationLink](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-disable-the-overlay-color-for-images-inside-button-and-navigationlink) is a good write up as well.