# When I add NavigationLink in SwiftUI, it takes the content into the background

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

When I add NavigationLink in SwiftUI, it takes the content into the background. How can I solve this problem?

My code:

```
 NavigationLink(destination: DrinksList()){
       VStack{
            Image("icecekler")
                 .resizable()
                 .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                 .cornerRadius(15)

             Text("İçecekler")
                 .font(.title)
                 .bold()

      }
}
```

Screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SGKF.png)

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-disable-the-overlay-color-for-images-inside-button-and-navigationlink

Comment: I want the picture to appear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI View displayed with blue background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58713872/swiftui-view-displayed-with-blue-background)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apply `.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())` on your `NavigationLink`

Answer (score 1):

Here is fix

```
 NavigationLink(destination: DrinksList()){
       VStack{
            Image("icecekler")
               .renderingMode(.original) // <<< this !!!
```